# Would you regret "of" not doing something?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"Would you regret of not doing something?"

Is this sentence ok? using "of" is correct? or using "for" or nothing?

Please help :)

Comment: Standard English doesn't require any preposition after _regret_: "Would you regret not doing something?"

Comment: Thanks Sven.. really helps.. but if I have mistakenly used somewhere, it'd be count as mistake?

Comment: Yes, it would. Perhaps I shouldn't complicate matters, but if you changed _regret_ from a verb to a noun, a whole new set of options would arise. For instance: "Would you feel regret about [or "at"] not doing something?" Maybe that's where some of your original confusion came from?

Comment: Thanks a lot for correcting.. I'm not sure if it's using as noun or verb.. Here is the whole sentence "If today were the last day of your life. Would you regret "of" not doing something?"

Comment: It's a verb in your sentence, and you should omit the "of." You would also want to make the two sentences one sentence, with a comma in place of the first period and a lowercase "w" in "would." You'll find that the companion site for English Language Learners (at http://ell.stackexchange.com/) is a more suitable place for you to find answers to questions of this type.

Comment: Your in-depth answer really helps Seven. Thank you so much for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is incorrect. 'Regret' is a transitive verb, which some people mistake for an intransitive.  You simply 'regret not doing something'. 'Not doing something' is the direct object. No prepositions are involved

It believe it can take an indirect object e.g. 'I regretted it at the time', 'I shall regret it until my dying day'. But I cannot think even of an indirect object which would be preceded by 'of'.

But I am willing to stand corrected by the grammaristas!

Comment: @user57406 As Sven says, other options come into play when you make 'regret' a noun. 'I have regrets about not inviting him', 'He lives with regret over Susie' , 'His regrets loomed large at the time' But again I cannot think of a way of introducing 'of' unless you said 'she had regrets of the highest order' - but that's an entirely different construction.

Comment: Thank you WS2. So I must remove "of" from this sentence? --> "If today were the last day of your life. Would you regret 'of' not doing something?" and must not add anything?

Comment: Yes that is right. But you have now, perhaps inadvertently,  made two sentences. You should remove the full stop after 'life' and the capital W in would.